# Writing into a file

Tags: c, linux, file

I have a very simple question regarding file write.

I have this program:

```
char buf[20];
size_t nbytes;

strcpy(buf, "All that glitters is not gold\n");
fd= open("test_file.txt",O_WRONLY);
write(fd,buf,strlen(buf));
close(fd);
```

What am confused is when I open the file `test_file.txt` after running this program I see some characters like `^C^@^@^@^^^@` after the line "All that glitters is not": Notice that portion of the buf is not written and those characters appear instead. Why is that so?

Comment: the string `"All that glitters is not gold\n"` is 31 characters in length.

Comment: quite stupid of me to not see that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're writing more than 19 chars in that buffer. Once you've done that, the behavior of your program is undefined. It could do whatever it wants.

Allocate a large enough buffer. It has to be able to fit all the letters plus a terminating `0` if you need to be able to treat it as a C string.

Answer (score 5):

The string `"All that glitters is not gold\n"` is longer than 20 characters.  I suggest you try it with a larger buffer.

Actually, if you're going to do any nontrivial work in C I suggest you never ever use `strcpy`, as a general habit.  Use functions like `strncpy` which let you specify a buffer size so that it's clear you'll never overflow.

Comment: +1 for warning about the use of functions that counts bytes written to buffers.

Answer (score 2):

libgcc `strcpy` Manual says:

> If the destination string of a
>   strcpy() is not large enough  (that 
>   is, if  the  programmer  was  stupid 
>   or lazy, and failed to check the size
>   before copying) then anything might
>   happen.  Overflowing  fixed  length
>   strings is a favorite cracker
>   technique.

Also the `strlen` says

> The  strlen()  function  calculates 
>   the  length  of  the string s, not
>   including the terminating '\0'
>   character.

So i guess `strlen ()` does not return what you expect it to return and as a result the extra characters are written

To make the thing work, you need to allocate a large enough buffer, which can hold the entire string.